# How far away is Jezero crater from Isidis Planitia? Can Perserverance go to Isidis Planitia?

Tags: rovers, perseverance, lander

according to [this map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Features_and_artificial_objects_on_Mars) Beagle 2's landing site (Isidis Plantina) isn't (too) far from Jezero Crater (landing site of rover *Perserverance*) If the rover were to turn around towards the location of Isidis Plantina, and drive non-stop, could Perserverance make it? If not, how close would it get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Perseverance landing site is at 18.44°N 77.45°E ([WP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octavia_E._Butler_Landing)) and the Beagle 2 site is at 11.53°N 90.43°E ([WP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_2)).

The straight-line distance between them, according to the [calculator at NSSDC](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/special/getMileage.action), is approximately 850km. This is about the same as the road distance from Paris to Munich, or San Francisco to San Diego.

Perseverance has so far gone approximately 13km over one and a half Earth years, so it is not likely to make an attempt at this sort of distance. The longest lifetime distance for a Mars rover was Opportunity's 45km over fourteen and a half Earth years; again, not really comparable.

Comment: Of course, neither was trying hard to go as far as possible since they were doing science at many stops along the way. But 850km is likely far in excess of the warranty...